# Tokenize - String to Array of Tokens

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, pandas, numpy

My code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import codecs
import re

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("tmp.csv", delimiter=",")
dataset = dataframe.values
x = dataset[:,0:1]
y = dataset[:,1]

#j = 0
for data in x:
    text = str(data[0])
    tokenizer = re.compile('\W+')
    tokens = tokenizer.split(text)
    i = 0
    for token in tokens:
        tokens[i] = token.lower()
        i += 1
    data = tokens
    #x[j] = tokens
    #j += 1
    print(data)

print(x)
```

While `print(data)` has the form `['token1', 'token2', ...]`
`print(x)` has the form `[["text1"], ["text2"], ...]`

I want the form `[['token1', 'token2', ...], ['token5', 'token6', ...], ...]` for x

`x[j] = tokens` instead of `data = tokens`with a counting index j returns in `ValueError: cannot copy sequence with size 4 to array axis with dimension 1`

tmp.csv has this form: [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P1OT3.jpg) with ca 3,5 million rows.

I'm relative new to python, so I hope anyone can help me.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the csv file contents

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code does not modify `x` in any way, hence you get the same list you had at the beginning, when you `print(x)`.

You need to create a new list where you'll store the tokenised text (i.e. a list of lists). Add `x_tokens = []` before the first for loop, then append each list of tokens with `x_tokens.append(tokens)`.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas
import codecs
import re

dataframe = pandas.read_csv("tmp.csv", delimiter=",")
dataset = dataframe.values
x = dataset[:,0:1]
y = dataset[:,1]

x_tokens = []

for data in x:
    text = str(data[0])
    tokenizer = re.compile('\W+')
    tokens = tokenizer.split(text)
    i = 0
    for token in tokens:
        tokens[i] = token.lower()
        i += 1

    x_tokens.append(tokens)

    print(tokens)

print(x_tokens)
```

Comment: Oh of course.... I didn't think about the fact that data is a temporary variable. Thank you!